# Custom LookumMulti Field that Stores Data in a Database

Tags: 2010

The problem with the standard SharePoint Multi Lookup Field is that I can't store more that 400-500 values in it because of the certain SPListItem limitations. We need to store at least 1000 lookup values per field, possibly more. I am about to start developing a custom field that stores the values in a database table. This field will be very complicated to develop. So, I've searched on the Interned just in case someone already did similar field in the past and found nothing.

Are there any database-based milti lookup fields you know or heard about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean that you need a field type like the  User field?

try to google *sharepoint entity picker*

Comment: Yes, this is a very nice control. I might even end up using it, but it has two fundamental problems i'm trying to solve: 1) It becomes impossible to work with if you have about 500 items selected and and want to delete one or two 2) validation of about 500-1000 SharePoint items will end up with timeout what is exactly the case with iLoveSharePoint's extended lookup with picker: http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/44989. I'm trying to store all data in SharePoint lists. The only thing I need to store in a Database is Lookups.